# Rails - Validated protected attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a scheduling system in Ruby Rails. The system is composed of Customers, Resources, and Bookings. There is many to one with Booking to Customer and Resources.  A customer and resource can have many bookings.

Booking has customer_id and booking_resource_id I thought should be protected. I also used booking_resource as the model because Resource conflicted with activeadmin.

I am using the validates_overlap gem that allows easily to create a overlapping validation with a scope to :booking_resource_id ( https://github.com/robinbortlik/validates_overlap) . The goal is we can never schedule the same resource at the same time.

The whole thing works under mass assignment but as soon as I put booking_resource_id as protected, add the individual assignments in the controller the validation is by passed.

How can I validate a protected attributed?

I read http://www.davidverhasselt.com/2011/06/28/5-ways-to-set-attributes-in-activerecord/ but I seem a little bit cornered. If I used attributes= and override mass assignment protected what is the point?

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :booking_resource
  attr_accessible :approved, :approvedBy, :end, :start, :title
  attr_protected :customer_id, :booking_resource_id
  validate :start_cannot_be_future
  validates :start, :end, :overlap => {:scope => :booking_resource_id}

  def start_cannot_be_future
    if self.start > self.end
      errors.add(:start, "Date can't be in the future")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I may have jumped the gun here... It appears setting @booking.customer_id = params[:booking][:customer_id] does validate, I was not seeing it because I did not have the correct redirect on failure in the controller, was just set to redirect back to index.

Answer (score 1):

First if you use attr_accessible then you don't need to use attr_protected because the attributes you don't make accessible will automatically be protected.

Second I don't see why you protect `booking_resource_id`. I mean, how can you know what's the resource to be booked? Yes maybe for editing it should be protected but for creating I don't think so.

So, if you need to specify different protected attributes I recommend you to take a look at the new [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) gem that will be included in the new Rails version. This gem provides you a nice way to specify wich attribues to be whitelisted in the controller and you can make different whitelists for each controller action wich I think you need in this case.